# How to initialize a PostGIS database in PostgreSQL single-user mode?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgis, postgresql-extensions

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.15 with PostGIS 2.0.7 through the standard packages available on CentOS 7 with EPEL.

I have a server script to automatically setup a PostGIS database, by first executing `initdb`, then using `postgres --single` to create a new database with PostGIS extension. This works roughly like this:

```
initdb -D ...

postgres --single -D ... postgres <<'EOF'
    CREATE DATABASE mydb;
EOF

postgres --single -D ... mydb <<'EOF'
    CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
EOF
```

However, the last command produces the following strange error message:

```
ERROR:  type reclassarg[] does not exist
STATEMENT:  CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

If I instead run the database server and execute `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` via `sql`, everything works fine:

```
postgres -D ... &

# Wait until service it up and running

psql mydb <<'EOF'
    CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
EOF
```

But that is not suitable for a database initialization script.

So how can I initialize a PostGIS database in PostgreSQL single-user mode?

**Update:** There is  [a thread in the pgsql-bugs mailinglist](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20150126124133.19763.60605@wrigleys.postgresql.org) on that topic, but that doesn't answer my question. It just explains that it is not planned to improve the single-user mode of PostgreSQL. So there will always be missing PgSQL language features to execute the current PostGIS extension creation script. **However**, most other PostgreSQL extensions can be installed in single-user mode just fine. So maybe there is a way to reformulate the PostGIS creation script so it achieves the same thing without requiring those language features, i.e. to make it "more portable".

*(This question originally appeared on StackExchange / GIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/214449/82644)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Someone previously ask a very similar question on the lists](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20150126124133.19763.60605@wrigleys.postgresql.org). Anyway, as told in the thread, [`reclassarg`](http://postgis.net/docs/reclassarg.html) is a composite type.

> RhodiumToad: Guest78493: in single-user, doing CREATE TYPE ... AS ...; 
>   doesn't create the array type
>
> RhodiumToad: Guest78493: it creates only the non-array one, but I have no idea yet why
>
> RhodiumToad: Guest78493: so for now, any extension with a CREATE TYPE AS won't load correctly in single-user
>
> RhodiumToad: Guest78493: arguably if it doesn't work it should error rather than quietly getting it wrong, so I think you're justified in calling it a postgres bug

Further, from Tom Lane himself!

> > [ Can't create postgis extension in single-user mode ]
>
> Why in the world would you think that's a good thing to do?
>
> Single-user mode is a barely-documented disaster recovery aid.
>   It's not meant for routine activity.  There are a *whole lot*
>   of behaviors you want that are turned off in single-user mode.
>
> The specific reason why this doesn't work is this bit in
>   heap_create_with_catalog:
>
> ```
> /*
>  * Decide whether to create an array type over the relation's rowtype. We
>  * do not create any array types for system catalogs (ie, those made
>  * during initdb). We do not create them where the use of a relation as
>  * such is an implementation detail: toast tables, sequences and indexes.
>  */
> if (IsUnderPostmaster && (relkind == RELKIND_RELATION ||
>                           relkind == RELKIND_VIEW ||
>                           relkind == RELKIND_MATVIEW ||
>                           relkind == RELKIND_FOREIGN_TABLE ||
>                           relkind == RELKIND_COMPOSITE_TYPE))
>     new_array_oid = AssignTypeArrayOid();
> ```
>
> We could possibly develop some other mechanism for detecting whether
>   we're within the initdb sequence, but I can't get very excited about
>   treating this as a bug.  Single-user mode hasn't been considered a
>   standard user environment since maybe the early 90s.

If it was you, please update us in the future and self-answer your questions when you get word from the horse's mouth.

## UPDATE.

> So maybe there is a way to reformulate the PostGIS creation script so it achieves the same thing without requiring those language features, i.e. to make it "more portable".

No, there is not. [ST_Reclass](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Reclass.html) requires it. The method you're using is not supported. Initializing a database is currently viewed as a different thing than `CREATE EXTENSION` on one. I don't think PostgreSQL intends `-single` to be used in that way, and certainly PostGIS doesn't intent to rewrite working code so it functions in PostgreSQL's unsupported modes, with outdated single-user contexts.